# Output 1, 0.5, or 0 depending if a matrix elements are prime, 1, or neither

Tags: matlab, for-loop, primes

I am sending a matrix to my function `modifikuj`, where I want to replace the elements of the matrix with:

- 1 if element is a prime number
- 0 if element is a composite number
- 0.5  if element is 1

I dont understand why it is not working. I just started with MATLAB, and I created this function:

```
function B = modifikuj(A)
    [n,m] = size(A);
    for i = 1:n
        for j = 1:m
            prost=1;
            if (A(i,j) == 1)
                A(i,j) = 0.5;
            else
                for k = 2:(A(i,j))
                    if(mod(A(i,j),k) == 0)
                        prost=0;
                    end
                end            
                if(prost==1)
                    A(i,j)=1;
                else 
                    A(i,j)=0;
                end
            end
        end
    end
```

With

```
A = [1,2;3,4]; 
D = modifikuj(A);
```

`D` should be:

```
D=[0.5, 1; 1 0];
```

Comment: @obchardon Don't make edits to the question which change code (other than formatting/indenting) - you might be changing / creating / fixing issues which make the expected fix different to the OP's original code!

Comment: Another thing to improve: you can loop over a matrix with one index: `for ii=1:numel(A), A(ii)...; end`. This will work for an array of any size, also 3D arrays, for example, and makes your code simpler and a little bit faster.

Answer (score 2):

In MATLAB you'll find you can often avoid loops, and there's plenty of built in functions to ease your path. Unless this is a coding exercise where you have to use a prescribed method, **I'd do the following one-liner to get your desired result**:

```
D = isprime( A ) + 0.5*( A == 1 );
```

This relies on two simple tests:

```
isprime( A ) % 1 if prime, 0 if not prime
A == 1       % 1 if == 1, 0 otherwise
```

Multiplying the 2nd test by `0.5` gives your desired condition for when the value is `1`, since it will also return `0` for the `isprime` test.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are not returning anything from the function. The return value is supposed to be 'B' according to your code but this is not set.  Change it to A.
2. You are looping k until A(i,j) which is always divisible by itself, loop to A(i,j)-1

With the code below I get `[0.5,1;1,0]`.

```
function A = modifikuj(A)
    [n,m] = size(A);
    for i = 1:n
       for j = 1:m
          prost=1;
            if (A(i,j) == 1)
                A(i,j) = 0.5;
            else
                for k = 2:(A(i,j)-1)
                    if(mod(A(i,j),k) == 0)
                        prost=0;
                    end
                end

                if(prost==1)
                    A(i,j)=1;
                else 
                    A(i,j)=0;
                end
            end
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @EuanSmith's answer. You can also use the in built matlab function in order to determine if a number is prime or not.

The following code will give you the desired output:

```
A = [1,2;3,4];

A(A==1) = 0.5;                %replace 1 number with 0.5
A(isprime(A)) = 1;            %replace prime number with 1
A(~ismember(A,[0.5,1])) = 0;  %replace composite number with 0
```

I've made the assumption that the matrice contains only integer.

If you only want to learn, you can also preserve the for loop with some improvement since the function `mod` can take more than 1 divisor as input:

```
function A = modifikuj(A)
    [n,m] = size(A);
    for i = 1:n
       for j = 1:m
            k = A(i,j);
            if (k == 1)
                A(i,j) = 0.5;
            else
                if all(mod(k,2:k-1)) %check each modulo at the same time.
                    A(i,j)=1;
                else 
                    A(i,j)=0;
                end
            end
        end
    end
```

And you can still improve the prime detection:

- 2 is the only even number to test.
- number bigger than A(i,j)/2 are useless

so instead of `all(mod(k,2:k-1))` you can use `all(mod(k,[2,3:2:k/2]))`

Note also that the function `isprime` is a way more efficient primality test since it use the probabilistic Miller-Rabin algorithme.

Comment: absolutely.  I'd go one step further and use all(mod(k,[2,3:2:sqrt(k)])), although, as you say, if efficiency really is a concern then just use the built-in matlab function.